# how to assign value to dynamically created textbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have created dynamic textbox using jquery for product name and product id,
i have created unique id for each textbox ,and i want to assign value to textbox.
my code is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var rIndex = $(".ProductName").length;
    var ndate = new Date();
    var time = ndate.getMilliseconds();

    var i = rIndex + time;
    var a1, a2;


    $("#lnkAddProduct").on("click", function () {


     var d = '<div class="addedProduct "><div class="control-group " style="margin-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" class="ProductName span2 pull-left" id="Product_Name_' + i + '" name="Product_Name" value="" placeholder="start typing to load products")"/><input type="text" class="ProductId" name="Product_Id" id="Product_Id_' + i + '" value="" /><a href="#" class="clsremove font-midium" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;" id="remove_' + i + '">remove</a></div></div>';

        $('#ProductList').append(d);
        alert("newID:"+i);

        //$(".clsremove").unbind("click").click(function () {
        //    $(this).closest(".addedProduct").remove();
        //});


        $('body').delegate(".ProductName", "focusin", function () {

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("NewvendorList","Product")',

            minLength: 1,

            select: function (evt, ui) {
                 a1 = ui.item.label;
                 a2 = ui.item.id;

                alert("label" + ui.item.label);
                alert("id" + ui.item.id);

                 $('#Product_Name_'+i).val(a1);
                alert("i===" + i);

                $('#Product_Id_'+i).val(a2)

            },
        });
      });
        i = i + 1;          
    });
});
```

$('#Product_Name_'+i).val(a1) for this line error occured as undefined.
how to assign value to value to textboxes.

Comment: It seems like the parenthesis and the next doublecuote should not be there:
placeholder="start typing to load products")"/> (this seems to be the problem )" )

Comment: if you provide a fiddle,it will be easy to see

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var rIndex = $(".ProductName").length;
  var ndate = new Date();
  var time = ndate.getMilliseconds();

  var i = rIndex + time;
  var a1, a2;


  $("#lnkAddProduct").on("click", function () {


  var d = '<div class="addedProduct "><div class="control-group " style="margin-bottom:10px;"><input type="text" class="ProductName span2 pull-left" id="Product_Name_' + i + '" name="Product_Name" value="" placeholder="start typing to load products")"/><input type="text" class="ProductId" name="Product_Id" id="Product_Id_' + i + '" value="" /><a href="#" class="clsremove font-midium" style="margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;" id="remove_' + i + '">remove</a></div></div>';

    $('#ProductList').append(d);
    alert("newID:"+i);

    //$(".clsremove").unbind("click").click(function () {
    //    $(this).closest(".addedProduct").remove();
    //});


    $(".ProductName").on("focusin", function () {

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("NewvendorList","Product")',

        minLength: 1,

        select: function (evt, ui) {
             a1 = ui.item.label;
             a2 = ui.item.id;

            alert("label" + ui.item.label);
            alert("id" + ui.item.id);

             $('#Product_Name_'+i).val(a1);
            alert("i===" + i);

            $('#Product_Id_'+i).val(a2)

        },
    });
  });
    i = i + 1;          
  });
 }); 
 replace your code with above and test it
```

Comment: Please don't just post code - explain what you have changed and why you changed it.

Comment: sorry, i replace '$('body').delegate(".ProductName","focusin",function () {' with
'$(".ProductName").on("focusin", function () {'
is it work ?

Comment: when you put 'on' or 'live', it is for dynamic data.so event defined without 'on' or 'live' will not work on live(dynamic) data. use of live or on is depends on jquery version

Comment: Do you even understand what `.delegate` does?

Comment: So basically, you've just written synonymous code that doesn't actually fix the problem, without explaining what you were doing and why you were doing it, and without even knowing what you were doing? Nice going! -slow clap-

Comment: my question is ,how to assign value to textbox. here  $('#Product_Name_'+i).val(a1);how to assign value to textbox whose id is #Product_Name_'+i.

Comment: Change in selector $('#Product_Name_"'+i+'"').val(a1);